# Get Textbox value inside Gridview using JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview and I created a textbox and button inside. I need to get the value of the textbox upon button click.

To make it simpler. I'll just post the fields needed inside the gridview: a textbox and a button.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Edit" OnClientClick="return validation();"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here's javascript :

```
function validation() {
  var dt = new String(document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>[name=TextBox1]").value);                
  if (dt == '') {
    //my code here
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It's not getting the value. :(
Please help, if you have encountered this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want get text box value according to button click. Please try this.

ASP.NET design.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Edit" OnClientClick="return validation(event);"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here jQuery Code

```
function validation(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var dt = $(target).closest("td").prev("td").find("[type='text']").val();
  alert(dt);
}
```

Please refer the jQuery, before running the code.

Comment: Nice answer, You can also make use of this too `.parent().prev().find("[type='text']").val();`

Comment: superb, worked for me, stuck in dev express grid but finally it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var GridView1 = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    for (var rowId = 1; rowId < GridView1.rows.length; rowId++) {
        var textValue = GridView1.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
        alert(textValue.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it but you're going to need to load in the jQuery library.

```
$('#Button1').on('click', function(){
    var textInput = $('#TextBox1').val();
    console.log(textInput);
    return textInput;
});
```

heres a link to it : https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: This won't work the **Textbox** is inside the gridview not on fly. One need to first access the grid then only you can access it's child control.